# filter and extract various parts of a table using input conditions from another file in linux

Tags: linux, loops, awk, filter

I have a file - list.txt

```
Name    CHR:BP  CHR BP
ABC 1:72837239  1   72837239
DEF 1:72837500  1   72837500
GHJ 1:72836456  1   72836456
FGG 1:72940273  1   72940273
GHF 1:72837490  1   72837490
```

I have another file which is a long list such as follows - region.txt

```
 Point  uniqID  ID  CHR pos p   start   end
5   ABC ABC 1   72837239    7.37E-8 72512988    74099273
61  DEF DEF 6   28354835    1.91E-9 25480328    29509596
```

I want to filter and save each filtered part of the file.
I have the following so far, which obviously doesn't work.

```
    cat region.txt | while read -r j ; do awk -F " " '{ if(($3 of list.txt == $j$4 ) \
&& ($4 of  list.txt >= $j$7 in && $4 of list.txt <= $j$8)) { print } }' list.txt > region_$j$1.txt  ; done
```

Here $j is supposed to be line number. My goal is to loop each line of region.txt to extract all the rows in list.txt where the Col3 is equal to Col4 of region.txt and values in Col4 of list.txt are between col7 and col8 of region.txt. Each of the filtered rows needs to be saved as file_Col1_value_of_region.txt. e.g. it will save as file_5.txt, and next file as file_61.txt

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, but I think you're just looking for:

```
$ cat list.txt 
Name    CHR:BP  CHR BP
ABC 1:72837239  1   72837239
DEF 1:72837500  1   72837500
GHJ 1:72836456  1   72836456
FGG 1:72940273  1   72940273
GHF 1:72837490  1   72837490
$ cat region.txt 
 Point  uniqID  rsID    CHR pos p   start   end
 5   1:72837239:C:T  ABC 1   72837239    7.37E-8 72512988    74099273
 61  6:28354835:C:G  DEF 6   28354835    1.91E-9 25480328    29509596
$ awk 'NR>1 && NR==FNR{hi[$4]=$8; low[$4]=$7; next} NR==1;  NR>1 && $4 < hi[$3] && $4 > low[$3]' region.txt list.txt
 Point  uniqID  rsID    CHR pos p   start   end
ABC 1:72837239  1   72837239
DEF 1:72837500  1   72837500
GHJ 1:72836456  1   72836456
FGG 1:72940273  1   72940273
GHF 1:72837490  1   72837490
```

Comment: Thank you. That works!.. How do i save each filter as its own file? I want to save each filter as different txt file. So i tried this `while read -r j ;do awk 'NR>1 && NR==FNR{hi[$4]=$8; low[$4]=$7; next} NR==1;  NR>1 && $4 < hi[$3] && $4 > low[$3]' regionlist.txt list.txt < test_$j ;done`